# Inject properties from Spring Cloud Config in Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, properties, inject, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

We have several applications trying to use centralise config provided by Spring Cloud Config backed by HashiCorp Vault.

One of this application is a Java EE batch (JSR 352) application using EJB schedulers. I will need to inject properties from the Spring Cloud config into this application **without using Spring framework**. What is the best way to do this?

It would be nice if we can do this by using something similar as @Value (similar to Spring application).

Answer (score -1):

Both  Spring Cloud config and EJB must receive parameters from environment.

Export environment variables: CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD....SOME_VALUE

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please?

Comment: You should set ENV variables like JAVA_HOME, my CONFIG_HOME, MY_URL, or EUREKA_URI=192.155.185.125:8888/eureka
Config file will read it like
 ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}